# CE Cache :escape Parsing on Custom System Messages Securit:ee Error

Tags: ce-cache, custom-system-messages

I've got one clusterf*** of a problem here:

I have 2 sets of [CE Cache](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ce-cache) `:escape` tags in my site's global header snippet:

```
{exp:ce_cache:escape}
  {if '{exp:cartthrob:unique_items_count}' > '0'}
    <span class="items">{exp:cartthrob:unique_items_count}</span>
  {/if}
{/exp:ce_cache:escape}

{exp:ce_cache:escape}
  {if logged_out}
    <a href="{path='member/login'}" class="login" data-reveal-id="login-modal">Login</a>
    <a href="{path='member/register'}" class="sign-up" data-reveal-id="register-modal">Sign Up Free</a>
  {if:else}
    <p class="logged-in"><span>Hi {exp:user:stats}{if first_name}{first_name}{if:elseif screen_name}{screen_name}{/if}{/exp:user:stats}</span> | <a href="{path='my-account'}"{if segment_1 == 'my-account'} class="here"{/if}>My Account</a> | <a href="{path='logout'}">Logout</a></p>
  {/if}
{/exp:ce_cache:escape}
```

That global header snippet is inside a [Custom System Messages](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/custom-system-messages) error template:

```
{embed='_global/document_head' page_title='{title}'}
<body class="single">
{header}

<article class="bizness">
    <header>
        <h1>{heading}</h1>
    </header>
    {content}
</article>

{footer}
{global_scripts}
{document_foot}
```

Now, for 99% of error messages, this setup works beautifully, no issues. But if I submit a bogus email on a [Securit:ee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/securitee) forgot password form, the CE Cache `:escape` tags return this text:

> -ce_cache_placeholder:94ec4f506cc81e96bf9b33205449ad19
>
> -ce_cache_placeholder:a612a2267145a9d4684fdffde5442c62

I don't even know where to start, people. Why is this one error different from the rest, and how can I fix those CE Cache errors?

- EE 2.6.1
- CE Cache 1.9.5
- Custom System Messages 2.5
- Securit:ee 1.3.6

Comment: What happens if you add a fourth tagpart to your escape tags? eg. `{exp:ce_cache:escape:cart}` and `{exp:ce_cache:escape:member}`.

Comment: @JasonVarga I still get that CE Cache `placeholder` code.

Comment: Do you have any native EE caching enabled? http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/ce-cache/viewthread/9180#31326)

Comment: @JasonVarga Nope! No caching across the board. In fact, even CE Cache itself is disabled for this site (while in development).